# is it possible to copy public path from current release into next release in laravel envoyer?

Tags: laravel, envoyer.io

I have a site that uses envoyer for deployment.

On my site users can save images/avatars/etc. These images are saved to the public path of laravel. `/public/uploads/`

The problem with this is that when I deploy an update, composer doesn't keep the new files in `/public/uploads` in the new release folder.

Is it to write a deployment script that'll copy everything from /public/uploads in the current release INTO the new release every time I push a new deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store them in `public/uploads`, store them in `storage/uploads`. Symlink `storage/uploads` to `/public/uploads` and move `storage/uploads` out of the project completely into it's own directory. Then symlink `/storage/uploads` to your own `/storage/uploads`, something like this:

```
ln -s /home/forge/storage/example.com/uploads /home/forge/example.com/storage/uploads
ln -s /home/forge/example.com/storage/uploads /home/forge/example.com/public/uploads
```

Make sure that the ownership of the new directory located at `/home/forge/storage/example.com/uploads` matches to your ownership of `/home/forge/example.com`.

This will allow persistence of storage on the device. Ensure that the `symlinks` are added to part of the deployment process, and you'll no longer lose your uploads each time you deploy.